# How can I get the type of thrown exception from CompletedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I use C# and Visual Studio 2012 to develop a WP8 application. I added a service reference to my project (Add Service Reference). So I am able to use webservice functions.

```
client = new YChatWebService.WebServiceControllerPortTypeClient();

client.getDataCompleted += client_getDataCompleted;
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
client.getDataAsync(); 

void client_getDataCompleted(object sender, getDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Error.Message

}
```

I have set up a timeout limit 500ms for `getData()`; If the time limit is exceeded then I get following error:

> "The HTTP request to 'http://example.com/webService/index?ws=1' has
>   exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may
>   have been a portion of a longer timeout."

That is nice :) However, I would like to find out what kind of exception was thrown. Something like a string variable containing a string "`TimeoutException`" would be nice. How can I achive that?

Comment: Would "if( e.Error is TimeoutException )" work? I am not sure what class the e.Error is, any documentation?

Comment: Thank you @ZombieSpy. "e.Error is TimeoutException" returns true.

Comment: what of `e.Error.InnerException` or `e.Error.BaseException`?

Comment: @MPeli i am not sure how things are done here, with a question answered in the comments (can one still set it to solved?) so i made an answer =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
if( e.Error is TimeoutException )
```

To see if the Exception is of the type TimeoutException

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this more that the http response from the server contains the error description, not a .net exception?

Does the e.Error class have any other properties other than 'Message'? If the server is also .net, then you might be able to match the exception type, but if it's not .net they won't correspond.

If there is an error code returned, I would just use this, or just search for the text 'exceeded the allotted timeout', to confirm that it was a timeout exception.